# Deleting flowfiles from apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

Below is the flow that I'm working on.

InvokeHTTP-->ExecuteScript-->ExecuteSQL

From invoke HTTP, I'm getting two flow files one with request and another with a response. I've configured ExecuteSQL with Event-Driven scheduling. Since there are two flowfiles in the queue after executing invoke HTTP processor, ExecuteSQL is being triggered two times which is generating duplicate data. I've added ExecuteScript processor with the below groovy code to remove one flowfile from the queue.

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def List<FlowFile> flowFileList = session.get(100)
def size = flowFileList.size();
log.error(size.toString())
int value = size as Integer;
def n=1;

for(FlowFile  k in flowFileList){
if( n!=value ){
session.remove(k)
}
n++;
}
```

But I'm getting below exception.

org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=27d84996-25a6-41a0-a3e8-06ed2354de18,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1592992841858-2, container=default, section=2], offset=18153, length=500],offset=0,name=72212066-7bcd-456b-ba97-252d18986f72,size=500] transfer relationship not specified

I've also added session.transfer(k,REL_SUCCESS) in for loop. But it's also not working. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here and suggest if there is an easier way of removing all flow files except one to implement the above scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have all the relationships from `InvokeHTTP` going into the next processor. Instead, direct the `Original`, `Failure`, `Retry`, and `No Retry` relationships to a different destination or *Auto-terminate* them at the `InvokeHTTP` processor. Then direct the `Response` relationship to the `ExecuteSQL` processor. You will not need the `ExecuteScript` processor as you will no longer have multiple flowfiles for a single HTTP call.

You should also set the `ExecuteSQL` processor to be *Timer-driven* again.

Comment: Andy, just another question, what would be the best way to pass only one flow file to the next processor, if a previous processor produces multiple flow files?

Comment: It depends on why you want to do that -- usually when you develop a flow, you want _every_ flowfile produced on a specific relationship to be consumed by the next processor in that flow. Why would you not want that to occur?

Comment: I'm inserting records into a table using a web service and I need to invoke a workflow after inserting all the records. For example, if the invoke HTTP processor inserts 3 records, it will produce 3 response flow files. As I've placed another invoke HTTP processor to invoke workflow service after the previous processor, it will be invoked 3 times. My use case is, irrespective of the number of records, the workflow should be invoked only one. So, I would like to remove all flow files except one so that workflow will be invoked only once.